# how to run two various functions in parallel in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to run two parallel functions in node. One function is for hit the API and return the result and Other function is for store that API result in MongoDB.1000 times i have to hit the API and store the result.

Comment: Before we can help, we need to know what you've tried.

Comment: are the functions promises? if so i suggest using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

Basicly js can run only one thing at one time. (I can recomend read more about event loop) Best you can do - use promises, with this its will be like parallel

You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) 
Also very userfull [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ), which i highly recommend